# c# webbrowser how to remove HtmlElement Attribute

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I can call `setAttribute()` for any `HtmlElement` in `WebBrowser` control, but how can remove it?

Is there any method like `removeAttribute()`?

**UPDATE:**

This is my code :

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("create_date_hour").SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
```

Now how can i remove `selected` attribute.

In above code, `selected` is just an example.

Comment: please provide some more details/code what you want to perform, so that we can help you

Comment: Ok, details updated. thanks for downvote!!

Comment: Really?? what is this down-vote for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the particular case you posted (the "selected" attribute) you can try and set the empty string in order to erase the value:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("create_date_hour").SetAttribute("selected", "");
```

I tried it with a WinForm WebBrowser and a series of `option` tags and it works.

To complete the picture, here's the code of my HTML test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select>
      <option>OPT-01</option>
      <option>OPT-02</option>
      <option id="togglingOption" selected="selected">OPT-03</option>
      <option>OPT-04</option>
    </select>

  </body>
</html>
```

and the significant fragments of my Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowserControl.Navigate("file:///C:/Temp/select.html");
    }

    private void toggle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowserControl.Document.GetElementById("togglingOption").SetAttribute("selected", "");
    }
}
```

(There is a button named "toggle" in the form)